# summary_factorlist, Having Error due variables with less than two levels

Tags: r

**I have a large data set including 2000 variables, including factors and continuous variables.*

For example:

```
library(finalfit)
library(dplyr)
data(colon_s)
explanatory = c("age", "age.factor", "sex.factor", "obstruct.factor")
dependent = "perfor.factor"
```

*I use the following function to compare the mean of each continuous variable among the level of the categorical dependent variable (ANOVA) or the percentage of each categorical variable among the level of the categorical dependent variable (CHI-SQUARE)*

```
summary_factorlist(colon_s, dependent ="perfor.factor", explanatory =explanatory , add_dependent_label=T, p=T,p_cat="fisher", p_cont_para = "aov", fit_id
= T)
```

*But as soon as running the above code, I got the following error:
Error in `dplyr::summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = ...$p.value`.
Caused by error in `fisher.test()`:
! 'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels*
*In the data set, there are some variables which do not include at least two levels or just one of their levels has a non-zero frequency. I was wondering if there is any loop function to remove the variable if one of these conditions satisfies.

1. If the variable includes just one level
2. If the variable includes more than one level but the frequency of just one level is no-zero.
3. if all values of the variable are missing*

Answer (score 1):

Update (partial answer):
With this code we can remove factors with only one level and keep other non factor variables:

```
x <- colon_s[, (sapply(colon_s, nlevels)>1) | (sapply(colon_s, is.factor)==FALSE)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My original data set includes 2000 variable with the above issues. I would be grateful if you read the question again.

Comment: Please see my update. The first question could be solved with this code.

Comment: Thank you so much, How about identifying the variables with more than one level but only one level has non-zero frequency. Such as  Age: 10-20 (freq: 10) , 20-30 (freq=0), 30-40 (freq=0)?

Answer (score 0):

The OP's code does work with the data provided

```
library(dplyr)
library(finalfit)
summary_factorlist(colon_s, dependent ="perfor.factor", 
   explanatory =explanatory , 
    add_dependent_label=TRUE, p=TRUE,p_cat="fisher", p_cont_para = "aov", fit_id = TRUE)
 Dependent: Perforation                      No         Yes     p                fit_id index
            Age (years)   Mean (SD) 59.8 (11.9) 58.4 (13.3) 0.542                   age     1
                    Age   <40 years    68 (7.5)     2 (7.4) 1.000   age.factor<40 years     2
                        40-59 years  334 (37.0)   10 (37.0)       age.factor40-59 years     3
                          60+ years  500 (55.4)   15 (55.6)         age.factor60+ years     4
                    Sex      Female  432 (47.9)   13 (48.1) 1.000      sex.factorFemale     5
                               Male  470 (52.1)   14 (51.9)              sex.factorMale     6
            Obstruction          No  715 (81.2)   17 (63.0) 0.026     obstruct.factorNo     7
                                Yes  166 (18.8)   10 (37.0)          obstruct.factorYes     8
```

The `str`cture of data shows the factor variables to have more than 1 level

```
> str(colon_s[c(explanatory, dependent)])
'data.frame':   929 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ age            : num  43 63 71 66 69 57 77 54 46 68 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Age (years)"
 $ age.factor     : Factor w/ 3 levels "<40 years","40-59 years",..: 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Age"
 $ sex.factor     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Sex"
 $ obstruct.factor: Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": NA 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Obstruction"
 $ perfor.factor  : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Perforation"
```

---

Regarding selection of `factor` variables with the condition mentioned, we could use

```
library(dplyr)
colon_s_sub <- colon_s %>% 
  select(where(~ is.factor(.x) && nlevels(.x) > 1 && all(table(.x) > 0) &
         sum(complete.cases(.x)) > 0))
```